# Assign value to variable in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Why am I not able to assign value to $rootScope with the following code.

```
 fetchIp().then(function(response){
        $rootScope.nodeIp = (response.length == 0 ? "localhost" : response[0]);

    });

var root = 'http://' + $rootScope.nodeIp + ':8080/';
```

It shows it as 'undefined'

Comment: You use this code into app.js or controller

Comment: Set root in the .then function. Since your code runs asynchronously nodeIP may not be set by the time you are executing the var root = 'http://' + $rootScope.nodeIp + ':8080/';

Comment: angular.module('Dashboard').factory('nodeServices', ['$http', '$q', '$location','$rootScope', function($http, $q, $location, $rootScope) {

Answer (score 1):

api call are async. Hence  `$rootScope.nodeIp`is undefined at the time when you using it out side the `.then`. You can use promise or the way I have done to get it working.

```
   var root = null;
   fetchIp().then(function(response){
        $rootScope.nodeIp = (response.length == 0 ? "localhost" : response[0]);
        root = 'http://' + $rootScope.nodeIp + ':8080/';

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern async/await.

```
const request = async () => {
    const response = await fetchIp();
    $rootScope.nodeIp = (response.length == 0 ? "localhost" : response[0]);
};

request();

var root = 'http://' + $rootScope.nodeIp + ':8080/';
```

More information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Did you solve your problem?